What is the name of this puzzle type? How to create one? nxn grid where you select n cells with different numbers
I want to create a specific puzzle, but I'm wondering if it already has a name, and if I can find some pointers on how to make it hard.
I have a NxN grid filled with numbers going from 1 to N.
I want to find the only set of N cells, that:

Range from 1 to N
Have one cell per row/column


Let me see if I understand you right: The solver is given an N*N grid of numbers going from 1 to N, and must select N cells that are all in different rows and different columns, and all contain different numbers? And you want to design such puzzles where there's only one solution?

Yes,exactly ! Thank you !

So basically sudoku but N doesn’t necessarily equal 9 and there is no 3x3 box constraint?

@EvanSemet No, you start with a filled grid, and to solve it you have to remove numbers until there are only N numbers left - one in each column, one in each row, one of each value.

The solution is called a transversal in an $n \times n$ array with $n$ symbols (for example, in a Latin square): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square#Transversals_and_rainbow_matchings
For a more colorful description, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_matching

Thank you! I wasn't specificaly looking for a latin square, I didn't mind if numbers repeated on rows/columns, as long as there was only a single possible transversal. But my question was quite large, so I'll mark the answer as solved, as it greatly helped me. Again, many thanks!
